# Como carregar PNG semi-transparente através de uma stream de memória?

Tags: delphi, imagem, stream-de-arquivos, delphi-xe3

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
public
  FBMP : TBitmap;

...
var
  PNG : TPNGImage;
  Stream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.LoadFromFile('foo.png');

  PNG := TPNGImage.Create;
  PNG.LoadFromStream(Stream);

  FBMP := TBitmap.Create;
  FBMP.Assign(PNG);

  PNG.Free;
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Quando tento desenhar a imagem acima, eu percebo que ela não reconhece a semi-transparência do arquivo PNG (mostrando todas as cores opacas), fenômeno que não acontecia quando eu não utilizava a *stream*. Mas como surgiu a necessidade de usar a *stream*, lá vai minha questão: como ativar a transparência quando carregando a imagem por `TMemoryStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi que é muito "gambiarroso" o que estou fazendo. A melhor prática seria usar apenas `TPNGImage`, desta forma:

```
public
  FPNG : TPNGImage;

...
var
  Stream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.LoadFromFile('foo.png');

  FPNG := TPNGImage.Create;
  FPNG.LoadFromStream(Stream);

  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Elimina algumas linhas, um falso *casting* desnecessário, não gera qualquer problema colateral e preserva as informações dos pixels semi-transparentes.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acredito que manipular a propriedade [`TransparencyMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage.TransparencyMode) de um componente `TPNGImage` deverá ser útil a você.

```
Uses pngimage;
// ...   
var
  PNG : TPNGImage;
// ...
begin
  // ...
  PNG := TPNGImage.Create;
  PNG.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  PNG.TransparencyMode := ptmBit;
  // ...
```

---

Essa propriedade não é somente leitura, com pode ser visto no trecho a seguir(*retirado da documentação*).

> Use `TransparencyMode` para determinar o modo de transparência a imagem
>   png usa....

Comment: Não é uma propriedade apenas de leitura?

Comment: `property TransparencyMode: TPNGTransparencyMode read GetTransparencyMode;` É sim. Essa é a declaração que se encontra na documentação que você postou o link. E indica que é somente leitura.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, acabei de tentar setar ela e o compilador não deixa por ser somente leitura. Quando a documentação diz "Use para determinar" é pra você saber qual é o tipo atual. E não pra modificar.

Comment: @TiagoC Você quer dizer `Transparent`?

Comment: Funcionou. Mas apenas a transparência total e não a semi-transparência. Mas eu já encontrei uma solução melhor.