# Como criar uma máscara sólida a partir de um Bitmap semi-transparente?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, imagem, bitmap

Desejo criar a imagem da direita, a partir da que está na esquerda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
var
  Image, Mask : TBitmap;
begin
  Mask := TBitmap.Create;
  Image := TBitmap.Create;
  Image.LoadFromFile('Yoshi.png');

// Criação da máscara aqui

end;
```

O resultado que procuro deve transformar `Mask` na imagem da direita para ser mostrada num formulário. Alguém sabe que tipo de método devo usar? Mexer diretamente com pixels? Ou quem sabe haja outro meio através dos *canvas*? Quem tiver qualquer ideia, mande aí.

Comment: Sei muito pouco sobre o assunto, porém, imagens semitransparentes são imagens sem fundo? Eu não sei como o Delphi reconhece esse tipo de pixel, e nem testei aqui. Mas qualquer cor de pixel diferente do valor reconhecido como cor de fundo (no caso do pixel transparente) você substitui pelo pela cor que você quer a máscara. Não seria por ai.. ?

Comment: Eu acho que se for para manipular a nível de pixels, seria por aí sim. Mas eu também nunca lidei diretamente com pixels no Delphi. Espero alguma direção com essa pergunta. E se por acaso alguém tiver uma maneira menos "coded" de fazer. Eu gostaria de saber.

Comment: Testei aqui e logo o primeiro pixel (0,0) já foi reconhecido como branco (#ffffff), então não seria uma fórmula perfeita tentar mudar a cor de tudo que for diferente de `clWhite`.

Comment: Seria necessário obter o valor Alpha de cada pixel. E preservá-lo caso for 0. Mas eu não sei como acessar este valor.

Comment: Bom, realmente não é minha praia. Veja se acha algo nesse **[link](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/index.html)**. Boa sorte!

Comment: Oi. Faz (muito) tempo que eu não programo em Delphi, então nem vou tentar preparar uma resposta. Mas, a sugestão do @Tiago é a forma mais fácil mesmo. Isso se chama [Limiarização (Thresholding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)), pois na prática você define um valor limiar e transforma a imagem original em binária fazendo cada pixel ser 0 se o pixel original estiver abaixo do limiar e 255 se estiver acima. Aqui há algumas formas de acesso (`bmp.Canvas.Pixels[x,y]` parece a mais fácil): http://ksymeon.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/getdibits-vs-scanline-vs-pixels-in.html

Comment: Espero que os links te ajudem, mas se você conseguir solucionar a sua dúvida por favor não esqueça de adicionar você mesmo uma resposta para servir de referência futura a quem mais precisar. :)

Comment: @Guill seja qual for o caminho utilizado, tente não usar 0 e 1 se possível, mas sim o alpha completo, senão as bordas vão ficar serrilhadas.

Comment: @Guill, a máscara vai ser usada para fazer formato customizado de janela? Aí provavelmente vai ter que converter em regiões.

Comment: @Bacco Não. A máscara vai simplesmente ser exibida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma possível solução:

```
var
  Image, Mask : TBitmap;
  i,j,Color   : LongWord;
  rowI, rowM  : pRGBQuadArray;

begin
   Color := $FF0000;

   Image := TBitmap.Create;
   Image.LoadFromFile('Yoshi.png');

   Mask := TBitmap.Create;
   Mask.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
   Mask.Width  := Image.Width;
   Mask.Height := Image.Height;
   FOR j := 0 TO Mask.Height-1 DO
   begin
      rowM := Mask.Scanline[j];
      rowI := Mask.Scanline[j];
      FOR i := 0 TO Mask.Width-1 DO
      begin       
         rowM[i] := ( rowI[i] and $FF000000 ) + Color;
      end;
   end;
   // ...use a máscara...
end;
```

> Compensa incluir um teste para se certificar de que `Image` também é `pf32bit` antes de criar a máscara.

Comment: Um cuidado: como não tenho o xe aqui, não sei se você tem `pRGBQuadArray`. De qualquer forma, tem que ser um tipo unsigned de 32 bits, teste e me diga, que ajusto a resposta. Se alguém puder testar e dar um feedback, vai ajudar.

Comment: copiei a estrutura `pRGBQuadArray` deste **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400819/how-to-implement-the-scanline-access-of-tbitmap-correctly)** no **SOen**. Porém, a linha `rowM[i] := ( rowI[i] and $FF000000 ) + Color;` não compila e retorna a mensagem: **"Operator not applicable to this operand type"**.

Comment: @Tiago experimente trocar o INTEGER pro RGBQuad. Qualquer coisa, se nao funcionar, adapto a linha pra tratar o R G B A separado. A vantagem se conseguirmos funcionar desta maneira é a velocidade. É muito mais simples trocar por operação com pixel, mas a performance é baixa. Outra coisa é evitar serrilhado, pois soluções com transparência 0 e 1 só tem um acabamento ruim.

Comment: desculpe, não entendi onde efetuar essa troca do `INTEGER pro RGBQuad`.

Comment: @Tiago escrevi errado, eu usei LongWord no lugar do Integer, por ser unsigned.

Comment: @Bacco desculpe a ausência. Vou poder testar somente amanhã.

Comment: @Bacco, mesma mensagem do Tiago. Não entendi como resolver.

Answer (score 10):

Desculpem a demora para comparecer, tenho andado muito ocupado. Parece é que nos faltou um pouco de pesquisa.

Se o ideal é trabalhar com `PNG` por conta da transparência, então trabalhar com `Bitmap` não está correto.

De fato, **[a partir do `Delphi 2009` com a introdução do `Unicode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage)** se tornou possível trabalhar com vários outros tipos de imagens, inclusive o `PNG`.

Aqui tem uma pergunta no **SOen** sobre o `TPNGImage`: **[how-do-i-get-pngs-to-work-in-d2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254952/how-do-i-get-pngs-to-work-in-d2009)**

@Guill, você mesmo lidou com o tipo TPNGImage nessa sua pergunta:**[Como carregar PNG semi-transparente através de uma stream de memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10886/como-carregar-png-semi-transparente-atraves-de-uma-stream-de-memoria)**.

Enfim, meu humilde método para tratar essa imagem:

```delphi
procedure TMainForm.btnCriarMascaraClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  png: TPNGImage;
  x,y: TColor;
begin
  png := TPNGImage.Create;
  try
    png.Assign(imgOrig.Picture);

    for x := 0 to pred(png.Width) do
      for y := 0 to pred(png.Height) do
      begin
        if png.Pixels[x,y] <> png.TransparentColor then
        begin
          png.Pixels[x,y] := clLime;
        end;
      end;

    ImgDest.Picture.Assign(png);
  finally
    png.Free;
  end;
end;
```

A seguir, o resultado!

[image: Imagem tratada]

É necessário que ter a `unit` `pngimage`. No XE3 está em `Vcl.Imaging.pngimage`.
Porém, se carregar a imagem em tempo de desing, a própria IDE do Delphi já adiciona uma referência para a mesma.

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizando a propriedade Canvas e FillRect.

Algo como:

```
procedure CreateBitmapSolidColor(Width,Height:Word;Color:TColor;const FileName : TFileName);
var
 bmp : TBitmap;
begin
 bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
 try
   bmp.PixelFormat:=pf24bit;
   bmp.Width:=Width;
   bmp.Height:=Height;
   bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
   bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Height, Width));
   bmp.SaveToFile(FileName);
 finally
   bmp.Free;
 end;
end;
```

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414929/how-i-create-bmp-files-bitmaps-of-a-single-color-using-delphi

Comment: Marcelo é boa prática referenciar a resposta que linkou, pode trazer para aqui (traduzir) parte dela também?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, infelizmente, a única coisa que essa procedure faz é criar um quadrado/retangulo com a cor passada.